# Representing C shift left signed char vs. unsigned char in Java

Tags: java, c, bit-shift, unsigned, signed

I am trying to port some C code into Java and have been struggling with interpreting the order of casting, operator precedence, and making sure the result is what I expect.  I've read numerous posts and think I have it figured out but want to be sure I've represented it correctly.

The [original C code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/75068205/) I am trying to port is this:

```
UInt32 _strtoul(char *str, int size, int base)
{
    UInt32 total = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (base == 16)
            total += str[i] << (size - 1 - i) * 8;
        else
           total += ((unsigned char) (str[i]) << (size - 1 - i) * 8);
    }
    return total;
}
```

In the code, a 4-byte value (either byte array or string) is converted into a 32-bit integer.  I am attempting to understand the difference in the two clauses in the conditional; specifically, what the practical effect of the `(unsigned char)` cast is.

From my understanding, in C, a byte is promoted to an int prior to the shift left.  However, I'm not understanding how that translates to the bitwise representation in C.  **Is it correct that in the top branch (base == 16, signed) a byte value of 0xff (-1) would be promoted from 0xff to 0xffffffff while in the bottom branch (unsigned) a value of 0xff (255) would be promoted from 0xff to 0x000000ff?**

Given this interpretation, is the following Java code a faithful representation (other than the Uint vs. int return type)?

```
public static int strtoul(byte[] bytes, int size, int base) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (base == 16) {
            // signed bytes, shifted
            total += bytes[i] << (size - 1 - i) * 8;
        } else {
            // unsigned bytes, shifted
            total += bytes[i] & 0xff << (size - 1 - i) * 8;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to port broken code?

Comment: You want to put parentheses around `bytes[i] & 0xff`, otherwise it's gonna get parsed as `bytes[i] & (0xff << (size - 1 - i) * 8)`. See [Java's operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Apart from that, your code looks valid to me, but you might wanna ask on [codereview.se] instead...

Comment: @EOF: Because that code is actually running on my OS X machine and used to return values from the SMC, such as the number of fans in my system, and I'm writing a Java version of that code.

Comment: @Siguza, thanks, I confused myself with the C order of precedence in the spaghetti of links and SO posts I was reading.

Comment: Well, this code is beyond broken. If you don't believe me, try calling `_strtoul()` on some test numbers, see what kind of results your get.

Comment: @EOF: I think whoever at Apple wrote this code was confident they knew it would work on their own numbers and not arbitrary test numbers.   In particular, I think it's all ascii text with byte values 32 to 127.

Comment: @DanielWiddis What gives you the idea that this was made by Apple (or anyone workign for them?)

Comment: @EOF the source code in the link in my initial post.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: Test your reading comprehension for **free today!!!!** Where is the `copyright Apple inc`, or anything to that effect?

Comment: @EOF Point taken.  Thank you for posting multiple comments criticizing the original code rather than answering the code question or suggesting another way to do it that doesn't port "broken code" which is the only code I can seem to find anywhere.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: Trust me, if you knew the slightest bit about C, you'd run away from this code screaming. This code is definitely worse than no code.

Comment: @EOF You're welcome to point me to any code for reading Apple's SMC information which does not originate from the C code I quoted, and is used in multiple open source products/projects like smcFanControl, istats, and others.  I don't "know the slightest bit about c" which is why I'm coding in Java and trying to read my system's SMC statistics.  Do you have a suggestion for a better way to do it?  Please do share.  Heck, post it as an answer and I'll accept it, and you can increase your reputation here.

Comment: @siguza can you please repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Java's operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), you're gonna need to put parentheses around `bytes[i] & 0xff`, otherwise it's gonna get parsed as `bytes[i] & (0xff << (size - 1 - i) * 8)`.

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
public static int strtoul(byte[] bytes, int size, int base) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (base == 16) {
            // signed bytes, shifted
            total += bytes[i] << (size - 1 - i) * 8;
        } else {
            // unsigned bytes, shifted
            total += (bytes[i] & 0xff) << (size - 1 - i) * 8;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not use sscanf because you are explitely looking for a uint32 solution. If you don't really care, it's as easy as

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int _strtoui(char *s)
{
    unsigned int ret;
    sscanf(str, "%u", &ret); /* use "%x" for hexadecimal */
    return ret;
}
```

I guess there is something like sscanf in Java, though. Anyway, here is my solution for `uint32_t`/`UInt32`. Beware of overflows in your input data. Also, the functions will give nonsense if the characters are not (hexadecimal) numbers. Improving that is another exercise.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t _strtoui32(char *str)
{
    int i;
    uint32_t total = 0;

    for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        total = total*10 + str[i] - '0';

    return total;
}

uint32_t _hextoui32(char *str)
{
    int i;
    uint32_t total = 0;

    for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        total *= 16;
        if(str[i] > 47 && str[i] < 58) /* base 10 number */
            total += str[i] - '0';
        else if(str[i] > 64 && str[i] < 71) /* uppercase A-F */
            total += str[i] - 'A' + 10;
        else /* lowercase a-f */
            total += str[i] - 'a' + 10;
    }

    return total;
}

uint32_t _hstrtoui32(char *str, int base)
{
    if(base == 16)
        return _hextoui32(str);
    else
        return _strtoui32(str);
}
```